# Windows Phone Panorama loads second item first

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

I am having a weird issue with my app. Even if I create a panorama page using the template from Visual Studio 2012, when I load the app, item 2 appears first, for a very short time, and then the view switches to item 1. I'm pretty sure it should not be acting like this. Any ideas what's happening?

```
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <controls:Panorama Title="my application">

        <!--Panorama item one-->
        <controls:PanoramaItem Header="item1">
            <Grid/>
        </controls:PanoramaItem>

        <!--Panorama item two-->
        <controls:PanoramaItem Header="item2">
            <Grid/>
        </controls:PanoramaItem>
    </controls:Panorama>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a standard panorama behavior. But you can fix it in this way:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    ... some lines missed ...
    Loaded="MainPage_OnLoaded">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <controls:Panorama x:Name="MainPanorama" Title="my application">

            <controls:PanoramaItem x:Name="DefaultItem" Header="item1">
                <Grid/>
            </controls:PanoramaItem>

            <controls:PanoramaItem Header="item2">
                <Grid/>
            </controls:PanoramaItem>
        </controls:Panorama>
    </Grid>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Item1 has a name, and subscription to Loaded event added.

Then in code-behind:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MainPage_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MainPanorama.DefaultItem = DefaultItem;
        }
     }
```